# My first Prime Faces Responsive project

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

For my bachelor degree I need to develop a responsive Web Application using JSF and Prime Faces. 
My problem is that I have no clue of how to start it. 
Can you recommend me what tools should I use (all of them)? Where can I find a "Hello world!" like tutorial, explained for users with no experience? From where can I get UI components like buttons, menus, etc? 
Thank you very much. 
PS: English is not my native language.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know why you asking it, because the answer is on the official site, they have learning section: http://www.primefaces.org/documentation 
It has a lot of information which I am sure will be enough for your project. 
All tutorials are easily found using google, here is one of them: http://www.journaldev.com/5516/primefaces-tutorial-with-example-projects